# Hyperlink color in firefox changes depending on URL

Tags: html, css, firefox, colors, hyperlink

I am new to html and css. I have 2 links one after the other. I have set the `a:link` and `a:hover` classes in css. The second link has a purple link color, where it should be silver. They both have a gold hover color which is as it should be. The second link color is correct if I change the link from `href="http://*******.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/Past%20Performances"` to `href="http://*******.co.uk/search/label/Past%20Performances"`. So by removing `.blogspot.` from the url. I tried it in Chrome and it doesn't seem to have that problem.

CSS:

```
a:link {
    color: var(--silver-color);
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:hover {
    color: var(--gold-color);
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

HTML

```
<a title="Send email to Erica" href="mailto:********@hotmail.co.uk" target="_blank">emailing us</a>.
<a title="Erica's blog page" href="http://********.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/Past%20Performances" target="_blank">Erica's blog</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to specify :visited selector

Comment: Just to add I made sure the order is first :link then :visited then :hover. Works now.